# c# Trying to make an array map work

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, drawing

```
public static void map_one()
    {
        const int width = 10;
        const int height = 5;

        int[,] map = new int[width, height] {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                             "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                             "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                             "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                             "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",};

        map[playerx, playery] = 1;
        for (height = 0; height < 20; height++)
        {
            for(width = 0; width < 20; width++)
            {
                Console.Write(map[width, height] + "");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

Im getting a problem with the array that you see over there, it tells me **"An array initialize of length '10' is expected**.Then for the code I wrote out to actually draw the whole thing out, in the loop I get a problem for both height and width **"The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"**

If you need any more info then please ask.

Comment: You're declaring your array as an `int` but initializing it with `string`s (i.e. `"0"`) not `int`s (i.e. `0`).  Not saying that's what's wrong, but it's one thing that is bad about what you're doing.  In fact, how does that even compile?  Or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the array dimensions when you initialize them

use it like so

```
  int[,] map = new int[,] {...}
```

Edit : also in you loop you set the limit of height and width as 20 , that will cause a runtime exception

do this instead :

```
int width = map.GetLength(0);
int height = map.GetLength(1);
```

Edit :

Your final code should look like this

```
    const int width = 10;
    const int height = 5;

    var map = new int[width, height];

    map[playerx, playery] = 1;
    for (int h= 0; h< map.GetLength(1); h++)
    {
        for(int w= 0; w< map.GetLength(0); w++)
        {
            Console.Write(map[w, h] + "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: you also created an array of type int , and init it with type string .

Comment: @ConfirmedSavage the compiler is smart enough to know, when you use the object initializer ( `{ ...}` ) after declaring your array, to count the width and height for you.  You can exclude them

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I switched things up and got this map to work again :D

Answer (score 0):

Few issues to note..

One:

> "0",};

syntax error right there :)

Two:

your width and height are declared "const". You cannot therefore assign any value to them post declaration.

Three:

> int[,] map = new int[width, height];

is all you need as by default all values in that array would be auto-initialized to 0.

Also, you cannot assign a string like `"0"` to an integer (int).

Comment: A trailing comma in a collection initializer is actually valid, the compiler ignores it.  E.g. `var[] test = new [] {"0",};`

Answer (score 0):

You initialized a 2D array with an 1D array
It should be something like

```
int[,] map = int[2,2] { {0, 0}, {0, 0}};
```

Secondly, the 2 index variables you used in the loop is the same with 2 const variable you declared at the start, index is supposed to change, but const, well.. is constant and cannot change.
Just use another variable for your index like

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        ...
```

And oh dont pass string value to an integer array